# Delete value with generic type only if it's a pointer

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, generics, delete-operator

Say you have a class such as:

```
template<typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    T value;
public:
    Foo(const T& value)
    {
        this->value = value;
    }
public:
    ~Foo()
    {
        if(std::is_pointer<T>::value) delete value;
    }
}
```

Now, obviously the compiler will throw an error if `T` isn't a pointer. Example:

```
Foo<int> foo(42);
```

Is there a way to successfully check if `T` is a pointer, delete it if it is, without a compiler error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a specialized helper class, something along the following lines:

```
template<typename T> class delete_me {

public:

   static void destroy(T &value)
   {
   }
};

template<typename P>
class delete_me<P *> {

public:

   static void destroy(P *value)
   {
       delete value;
   }
};
```

And your destructor:

```
~Foo()
{
    delete_me<T>::destroy(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply assume that the resource manages itself. If your variable of type `T` don't free resources, then assume it's the expected behavior.

For example, if you have a non owning pointer that you pass to your class template, you don't want it to delete it, since the pointer is non owning.

On the other hand, a `std::unique_ptr` will free the pointer it contains automatically.

Let's say you have a singleton `Bar`, and has a function `Bar::instance` that returns a `Bar*`:

```
// You don't want Foo to delete instance
Foo<Bar*> foo{Bar::instance()};
```

But with a unique pointer, it will look like this:

```
Foo<std::unique_ptr<Baz>> foo{std::make_unique<Baz>()};
```

The pointer to `Baz` will free itself, just like you intended.

TL; DR You already have the best solution if you simply remove your destructor.